# Why is a callback action pointing to a method other than was assigned?

Tags: c#, callback, delegates

I am trying to pass a method with parameters as a callback action. My approach is to assign a callback action through a delegate. However, when I invoke the callback, the method I used in a delegate is not being called. Instead, a method I declared the callback in is being called. Why is that?

I've been using this approach many times before and it always worked the intended way.

In the picture below I would expect the callback's method name to be "OnPhaseFinished" rather than "StartCurrentPhase":

[image]

Comment: I do not undestand your question `StartCurrentPhase()` calls `_currentPhase.Activate()`, wich in turn calls the function `callback()`. That is just a basic chain of Method calls, as it has been since we "invented" the call stack. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: @Christopher when I call callback.Invoke() I would expect OnPhaseFinished to be called but instead StartCurrentPhase is being called.

Comment: Okay, I seriously think I am missreading you. Because I read: when you **start** a method call you expect the **callFinished** code to run?

Comment: Nothing in your question suggests that invoking the delegate will call `StartCurrentPhase`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put your code into SharpLab, and see what the compiler generates.

I'm using this code, which approximates the code in your question:

```
using System;
public class C {
    private Phase _currentPhase;

    private void StartCurrentPhase()
    {
        Action callback = delegate { OnPhaseFinished(_currentPhase); };
        _currentPhase.Activate(callback);
    }

    private void OnPhaseFinished(Phase currentPhase)
    {
    }
}

public class Phase
{
    public void Activate(Action callback) { }
}
```

The compiler then generates:

```
public class C
{
    private Phase _currentPhase;

    private void StartCurrentPhase()
    {
        Action callback = new Action(<StartCurrentPhase>b__1_0);
        _currentPhase.Activate(callback);
    }

    private void OnPhaseFinished(Phase currentPhase)
    {
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private void <StartCurrentPhase>b__1_0()
    {
        OnPhaseFinished(_currentPhase);
    }
}
public class Phase
{
    public void Activate(Action callback)
    {
    }
}
```

[See here on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ6QA5QCWAbgIYAuMpACgAtOAZz4B9MAFcosAHbchomAG56jdQxYcefDClIBlbpyjdKM+YuFiAFAEpNtJ43I4spMJwA234JzAAa1IAXlIAExhvGABzXVpSAHk5JTEAMVY5VhFBGHDbSUsYBVSYexVSAF81AldXQtli62UAOgBBMG4dXlsvX38g8qdKpydtLl5yA2TSjKycvNtSzyKSmzKnOlrGEYJdwhJyD1LCLddD/VIOromYWwx3Tx8/AMD7BN3KoA=)

You can see that the compiler's turned your `delegate { OnPhaseFinished(_currentPhase); };` into a private method on the `C` class:

```
private void <StartCurrentPhase>b__1_0()
{
    OnPhaseFinished(_currentPhase);
}
```

It then creates an instance of the `Action` delegate, pointing to this generated `<StartCurrentPhase>b__1_0` method.

This is how the compiler implements anonymous delegates (and lambdas): by creating a new private method (sometimes on the current class, but sometimes on an entirely new class).

It happens to have named the `<StartCurrentPhase>b__1_0` method it generated after the name of the method which contains the anonymous delegate, but that's entirely its decision -- it could have named it anything it liked.

This **does not** mean that invoking the delegate somehow calls the `StartCurrentPhase` method. You can see that it invokes the `<StartCurrentPhase>b__1_0` method (which is **different** to `StartCurrentPhase`), which in turn invokes `OnPhaseFinished(_currentPhase);`.